# static variable in php during one user request

Tags: php

I try to use a variable in each instance for a class.

My example class:

```
class test {
    private static $gvalue;

    function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->gvalue = $value;
    }

    function getValue()
    {
        return $this->gvalue;
    }

}
```

Now I create to instances of this class "test" and print out some values.

```
$obj = new test();
$obj2 = new test();
echo "1: ";
echo $obj->getValue();
echo " / ";
echo $obj2->getValue();
$obj->setValue("green");
echo "<BR>2: ";
echo $obj->getValue();
echo "/";
echo $obj2->getValue();
```

My expectation was to get the following output:

1: / 
2: green/green

But the result is:

1: / 
2: green/

Did I understand something wrong? Or ist that not possible in PHP?
Goal at the end. I would like to set some variables/arrays during the creation of an instance (__construc) and us that for every instance during the code (per user request).

Comment: When using static variables you can only use the double colon :: to work with them

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: Static variables are associated with the entire class, not a specific object. That's why you don't use `$self` to access them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change how you access the static property in your method implementation:

```
<?php

class Test {
  private static $gvalue;

  function setValue($value) {
    self::$gvalue = $value;
  }

  function getValue() {
    return self::$gvalue;
  }
}

$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new Test();
echo sprintf("1: %s/%s\n", $obj1->getValue(), $obj2->getValue());

$obj1->setValue("green");
echo sprintf("2: %s/%s\n", $obj1->getValue(), $obj2->getValue());
```

The output of that is:

```
1: /
2: green/green
```

Answer (score 0):

You only set `$gvalue` for `$obj`:

```
$obj->setValue("green");
```

When you `echo $obj2->getValue();` the value of `$gvalue` is still nothing, because you didn't set it for `$obj2`.

`$obj` and `$obj2` are both different instances of the same class. They have the same characteristics etc. but they can hold different values. Thus the output that you got:

```
1: / 2: green/
```

is the correct output.

Comment: @arkascha Ah, I see. I'll leave this answer here for extra information, your answer is the correct answer.